# Take file information?

Tags: php, file, upload

So I know how to upload a file to a web-server with PHP. Instead of uploading it though, I just want to read the data from the file and use it, WITHOUT the upload part. Could someone link me up or give me an example plz?

Comment: How do you want to read the data of a file on the server without uploading this data to the server?

Comment: I do not think that is possible. PHP is a server side language, it cannot read a client-side file. Javascript, does not allow to read file on the local machine (except with activeX IE only). Could you explain why you want that??

Comment: if you want to read some user's data (a file), you need to read a file already uploaded... there's no way to read a file that is not yet uploaded on the server

Comment: To be able to read the file, you need it to be uploaded to the server. Pretty hard to read a file that you don't have. You don't have to use the file after it's been uploaded and you've read it (since it's probably placed in a /tmp folder somewhere and will be cleaned up at some point by the system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from HTML, the file is always uploaded to the server, to a temp directory. if from PHP you don't move it to another directory, it will be deleted later, but you can still use it and read it on the script that handles the upload, as shown in the example of [is_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is to send the data of the file via POST and work with it via something like

```
$postData = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
```

PHP is a server-side language, which means it either needs a server-side copy of the file (since it can't access the client) or you need to send parts of the file via common HTTP request methods that PHP can work with (POST or even GET)

There may be a way using JavaScript, but I can't think of any

Comment: So yeah, the solution is to upload the file.

Comment: Is there a way to read from the temp file and then discard it?

Comment: @Ken yes, i've put an example of using the temp file on my answer

Answer (score 0):

a javascript possible solution:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader

not cross-browser, works only in firefox and webkit html5 api compatible versions